# Execute process does not fail, nor does the lateral effects

Tags: android, process

Something like

```
private void loadFromDirectory(String _dir) {
    Process p;
    String pCommand;
    System.err.println("loadFromDirectory: " + _dir);
    try {
        pCommand = "rmdir /synth*";
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pCommand);
        System.out.println(p.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        pCommand = "mkdir /synth" + (int)Math.random()*1000;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pCommand);
        System.out.println(p.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        pCommand = "pwd";
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pCommand);
        System.out.println(p.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is running all the way and does not throw an Exception until `pwd` execution (Java.io.IOException: Permission denied).

A stepping run with the debugger while monitoring the filesystem with an `adb` interactive shell shows the lateral effects of folder creation and deletion are not happening.

Got ideas?

**Edit**: Am trying some things... maybe `COMMAND` is behaving differently from  `sh -c 'COMMAND'`

Comment: Am sorry that `System.out.println(p.getInputStream())` is lame, but please keep up with the main question that the lateral effects are not happening when spying the virtual device with `adb shell`.

Comment: Finally `sh -c COMMAND` got the work done, and people from [freenode](http://freenode.net) told is true that `sh -c COMMAND` often behaves better than `COMMAND`, but the reason keeps to be unknown to me.